# What is the storage hit for only using 10 character of a nvarchar(100) vs a nvarchar(255)?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I need to balance available disk space with the expected size of data.  What sort of hit to storage occurs when there is unused space?

Example: "dog" being stored in nvarchar(10) vs nvarchar(100).  If I plan for the worst, and choose nvarchar(100) instead of nvarchar(10), how much extra disk space is being wasted if I go with nvarchar(100)?

Comment: Did you search? [The documentation](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi-2Ja9l9PaAhUKJsAKHTLcD3YQFjABegQIABAs&url=https%3A%2F%2Ftechnet.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fms186939(v%3Dsql.110).aspx&usg=AOvVaw3mRrZER-ULJKc3ZK1YGmcu) appears to be very clear on this: _"The storage size, in bytes, is two times the actual length of data entered + 2 bytes."_ So, the maximal size should not matter.

Comment: If you make it nvarchar(10) you won't be able to put anything larger than that in your column... so this would cause a larger issue. Also, no need to use nvarchar if you aren't expecting unicode.

Comment: To be fair, I didn't find a clear dupe, so this one has that going for it. If anyone wants the MySQL equivalent, though, see here: [Is there any difference between varchar(10) and varchar(1000) when we store string whose length is less than 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184759/is-there-any-difference-between-varchar10-and-varchar1000-when-we-store-stri)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nvarchar` storage size is 2 bytes per char + 2 extra bytes. The maximum length of the column doesn't matter - the storage size is determined by the actual data.

From [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> **nvarchar [ ( n | max ) ]**
>   Variable-length Unicode string data. n defines the string length and can be a value from 1 through 4,000. max indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^30-1 characters. The maximum storage size in bytes is 2 GB. **The actual storage size, in bytes, is two times the number of characters entered + 2 bytes.** The ISO synonyms for nvarchar are national char varying and national character varying.

(emphasis mine)

However, Please **do not** consider this a recommendation to use `nvarchar(max)` for everything. Since `max` is treated differently, it has some nasty side effects (performance hits).

Generally speaking, you should choose the column max size by your estimated actual data size. To be on the safe side, you might want to simply set the max size twice the expected size.

If you **know** you are only going to use a single ASCII supported language, you should consider using `varchar` instead of `nvarchar`, since it's storage size is half the storage size of `nvarchar`:

> **varchar [ ( n | max ) ]** Variable-length, non-Unicode string data. n defines the string length and can be a value from 1 through 8,000. max indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes (2 GB). **The storage size is the actual length of the data entered + 2 bytes.** The ISO synonyms for varchar are charvarying or charactervarying

(Again, emphasis mine)

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks for your comment. your first subject is also described in iamdave's answer

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can remember and as Zohar has mentioned, there is very minimal difference in storage.

---

You *will* however, see potentially big impacts on query memory grants and therefore the overall performance of your server.  As the Query Engine has no idea just how full those larger string columns actually are, it tries to allocate *probably* enough memory assuming many filled columns.

For further reading, go [here](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/02/memory-grants-data-size/).